# Autotools per subproject LIBS possible?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, libtool

I have a recursive autoconf + automake project that is structured like this:

```
+
|- configure.ac
|- Makefile.am
|- Makefile.in
|- ...
|-- (subdir1) --+
|               |- Makefile.am
|               |- source.c
|               |- ...
|
|-- (subdir2) --+
|               |- Makefile.am
                |- source.c
                |- ...
```

The top level configure/Makefile checks if various libraries are available (AC_CHECK_LIB), then builds the libraries in the subdirs (if selected).

The problem is the LIBS variable that is passed down to each subdir make contains the union of all required libraries, ie:

```
# each subdir sees:
LIBS = -lfoo -lbar -lbaz -lbif
```

But what I want is:

```
# subdir1 gets
LIBS = -lfoo -lbar

# subdir2 gets
    LIBS = -lbaz -lbif
```

Is there a mechanism to specify per subproject LIBS?

Answer (score 2):

In your toplevel Makefile.am use a variable name per library

`LIBFOO = -lfoo`

`LIBBAR = -lbar`

in the subdirectories refer to $(LIBFOO) and $(LIBBAR)